# Html2Canvase -> on scroll image is empty

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

on click -> i m adding a div with absolute position in a DIV which has specific Height and Width  (vertical scroll) in which user input its data and on save i use html2canvas to convert html to image.

```
  var element = angular.element("#beforeComment_" + index);
    html2canvas(element).then(function (canvas) {

    var _Image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var _img = _Image.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");                     
                });
```

if div is in visible area it works perfect but as i use window scroll to move position DIV down i get blank image.

but as compared to if i use

```
html2canvas(window.document.body).then(function (canvas) {

        var _Image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var _img = _Image.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");                     
                    });
```

it works perfect even i scroll or drag drop Div.

it would be better if there is pluker to make things more clear but i got complex html structure and it will add more complexity

[image: Image to describe the issue]

can some one help :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('#beforeComment_' + index));
```

Also, check if '#beforeComment_' + index actually exists.

Comment: i have tired that before and element does exit even in html2canvas        var node = ((nodeList === undefined) ? [document.documentElement] : ((nodeList.length) ? nodeList : [nodeList]))[0];                                                 node does have the value of element that i passed but i dont know, where it get skipped . as there is no much documentation in html2canvas because of that i cant find out whats really happening